# Deploying Smart Contract to Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, wallets, rinkeby

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy my smart contract to `Rinkeby` using `Truffle`:

```
Error: Unknown arguments format passed to new HDWalletProvider. Please check your
configuration and try again
```

Note: I haven't had any problems deploying this same contract locally using `Truffle`, only to `Rinkeby`.

Here's my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');  

module.exports = {
  networks: {
     development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",     
        port: 8545,            
        network_id: "*",   
     },

     rinkeby: {
        provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(process.env.RINKEBY_MNENOMIC, 
        "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}"),
         host: "127.0.0.1", 
         network_id: 4,
         gas: 4612388,
         gasPrice: 10000000000
     },
 },

 // Configure your compilers
 compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.6.2",  
    }
 }

}
```

I'm wondering if this is some sort of version issue cause I'm seeing that my previous contracts used `'truffle-hdwallet-provider'`, while this one is using `'@truffle/hdwallet-provider'`

Meanwhile, my `.env` file contains the following:

```
#MNENOMIC="word1 word2 word3, ...word12"
RINKEBY_MNENOMIC="word1 word2 word3, ...word12"
PRODUCTION_MNENOMIC="word1 word2 word3, ...word12"

INFURA_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

So what might be happening here? What is this  `Unknown arguments format passed to new HDWalletProvider` error all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it *was* a version thing.

According to Truffle's official `readme` (available here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider#truffle-usage) the way to do this now is as follows:

```
rinkeby: {
  provider: () =>
    new HDWalletProvider({
      mnemonic: {
        phrase: rinkebyMnemonic
      },
      providerOrUrl: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + infuraKey,
      numberOfAddresses: 1,
      shareNonce: true,
    }),
  network_id: '4',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try installing the wallet handler with the following commaind:

```
#~>npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider
```

Then on your truffle-confi.json have the following:

```
var mnemonicPhrase = "word1 word2 word3 ....word12";
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
        // must be a thunk, otherwise truffle commands may hang in CI
      provider: () =>
      new HDWalletProvider(mnemonicPhrase, "https://rinkeyb.infura.io/v3/YOUR-INFURA-PROJECT-KEY"),
      network_id: '4',
    }
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.9',
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
};
```

then try run with truffle: truffle migrate --network rinkeby

You can also replace the infura "https://rinkeyb.infura.io/v3/YOUR-INFURA-PROJECT-KEY" with Alchemy  "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/YOUR-ALCHEMY-JEY"